# Failure in QuickBlox integration Login/Signup not happening

Tags: ios, iphone, chat, quickblox

I have integrated QuickBlox iOS SDK for chat in my app . But login not happening getting error in log

> [QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999
>   "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} 2016-08-17 16:10:33.207
>   MediEN[270:54815] [QBCore] Response error reasons: {
>       error =     {
>           message = cancelled;
>       }; } 2016-08-17 16:10:33.208 MediEN[270:54815] [QBAuth] Create Session request error: (null) 2016-08-17 16:10:33.221
>   MediEN[270:54898] [QBCore] Response error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} 2016-08-17 16:10:33.222
>   MediEN[270:54898] [QBCore] Response error reasons: {
>       error =     {
>           message = cancelled;
>       }; }

please find below code for initialisation and signup .

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:44907];
[QBSettings setAuthKey:@"qha5pegavkq-n-K"];
[QBSettings setAuthSecret:@"BTFsj7Rtt27DAmT"];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:@"Ep97pSstBQ9WQfw"];
[QBSettings setChatDNSLookupCacheEnabled:YES];
[QBSettings setServiceZone:3];
 QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
 user.login = @"kuriakose2";
 user.password = @"kuriakose37";


[QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser * _Nullable user) 
{
     [self showAlertWithMessage:response.debugDescription         title:response.description];
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) 
{
[self showAlertWithMessage:response.debugDescription title:response.description];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer, my **AuthSecret** was wrong.